# What should be the ideal fallback method?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using Ajax to call for a special file if JavaScript is enabled and if it is disabled then it loads the regular file.

My Code is like this:

```
    window.onload = function() {
      document
        .getElementById("wrapper")
        .innerHTML = "<img src='cdn/img/demo/loading.gif'>";
      var x = null;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {

        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

        var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {

        // code for IE6, IE5

        var x = new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0');
      } else {
        // @TODO - Fallback
        // My Question : What should be an ideal Fallback method here?
      }
      x.open("GET", "js_enabled.php", true);
      x.send("");
      x.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (x.readyState == 4) {
          if (x.status == 200)
            document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = x.responseText;
          else
            document.getElementById("wrapper").innerHTML = "Error loading document";
        }
      }
    }
```

What should be an ideal Fallback method in the first block?

**UPDATE:**
The fallback is for the browsers. As you see that those commands are for IE and normal browsers. I want to know if god forbid some browser does not understand ant of those 2 commands then what?

Comment: I'm confused, are you actually talking about if AJAX is available or not? You say JavaScript BUT if JavaScript isn't available NON of that code will run?

Comment: Maybe you should put `return;` as the fallback.

Comment: I'm *guessing* he means if JS is available, but AJAX isn't. Judging from his code example that seems to make sense.

Comment: How about using some kind of JavaScript framework instead (jQuery?). It will take care of differences between browsers (it seems you ask about browser compatibility, not fallback). If a browser supports JS but not AJAX, then it is so archaic that even the oldest indians don't remember it. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX is extremely likely to be available if JS is available, so it's not something you'll have to deal with often, but if you're looking for a fallback when AJAX isn't available (which I'm guessing you are from your code example), then the only real way of doing that is making sure that your page works fine without it.

Links should point to appropriate pages (or just to reloading the current page) and then be overwritten with the JS to use AJAX (but only if AJAX is available). That way you'll have a functioning site even if JS isn't available, let alone if AJAX isn't.

To give you some idea of how small the problem is when it comes to lack of AJAX support, according to [this site](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=1277014) browsers that include AJAX support include the following:

- Internet Explorer 5.0 and up
- Opera 7.6 and up
- Netscape 7.1 and up
- Firefox 1.0 and up
- Safari 1.2

As you can see, that's some pretty old stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you are confused if javascript is disabled then there will be no fallback method. Assuming that you mean anabling/disabling of javascript.

Then what you do is fill up the area with default text and hide it using js.
 so if JS isnt enabled the default text will be shown to the user. 
and if js is enabled the default text will be hidden almost as soon as it is rendered and then your ajax thing will take over